# linking springboard in iOS tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, theos, logos

I'm trying to develop a simple ios tweak that uses some springboard components. I've dumped the headers and included the one I need (SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h), but when I compile I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NotificationSwipe.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried copying the SpringBoard binary from phone and adding it under Link Binary with Libraries in xcode. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't have class implementation or library it defined in you have to obtain the class at runtime. This is what `objc_getClass` function is for. It returns an objc class at runtime and gives you the ability to use the class without knowing anything about him at compile-time.

Just replace `SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView` with `objc_getClass("SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView")`.

I suggest you read about objective-C runtime. Developing tweaks requires you to understand at least basics in which case you wouldn't ask this kind of questions.